# How to stop previous animation by starting a new loop in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have 6 objects to be animated. Animation starts after loading the page by the first circle and continues one by one. The point is that it should be restarted at any time by clicking any of circles, should be started from that circle and should be continued by the next on the right. Problem is that after clicking, the previous loop doesn't stop and continues to play both - previous and new one. What should I add to the code to make it work properly?

I've tried adding different values of "end" attribute, but none of them worked

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 640 480" enable-background="new 0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
   <animate id="1p_anim" xlink:href="#_1p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
  />
  <animate id="2p_anim" xlink:href="#_2p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1p_anim.end; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="1s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
  />
  <animate id="3p_anim" xlink:href="#_3p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2p_anim.end; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
  />
  <animate id="4p_anim" xlink:href="#_4p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="3p_anim.end; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
 />
  <animate id="5p_anim" xlink:href="#_5p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="4p_anim.end; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
 />
  <animate id="6p_anim" xlink:href="#_6p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="5p_anim.end; click" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  end="1p_anim.click; 2p_anim.click; 3p_anim.click"
 />
</defs>
<g id="1p">
 <circle id="_1p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" cx="103.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="2p">
 <circle id="_2p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="158.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="3p">
 <circle id="_3p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="210.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="4p">
 <circle id="_4p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="262.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="5p">
 <circle id="_5p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="314.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="6p">
 <circle id="_6p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="366.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau My fault, have updated with a code snippet. That way will be easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this use case is a bit too complicated for the standard animation feature.

I would suggest just using a little bit of Javascript.

```js
var circleElements = document.querySelectorAll("svg circle");
var animateElements = document.querySelectorAll("svg animate");
var currentIndex = -1;
var timeoutHandle = null;

circleElements.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  // Add a click event listener to all the circles 
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    circleClick(index);
  });
});


function circleClick(index) {
  // A circle has been clicked on
  currentIndex = index;
  // Trigger the animation of this circle
  animateElements.item(currentIndex).beginElement();
  // Clear any timeout that is running
  clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
  // Start a new timeout which, when it expires, will trigger the animation on the next circle
  timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
    nextCircle();
  }, 1000);
}

function nextCircle() {
  // We have been called by a timeout.
  // Incement the index
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex < animateElements.length) {
    // If we are not yet at the last circle, trigger the animation on the new circle
    animateElements.item(currentIndex).beginElement();
    // Start a timeout for the circle after this one.
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
      nextCircle();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

// Start animating right away with the first circle
circleClick(0);
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 640 480" enable-background="new 0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
   <animate id="1p_anim" xlink:href="#_1p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  />
  <animate id="2p_anim" xlink:href="#_2p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="1s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  />
  <animate id="3p_anim" xlink:href="#_3p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
  />
  <animate id="4p_anim" xlink:href="#_4p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 />
  <animate id="5p_anim" xlink:href="#_5p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 />
  <animate id="6p_anim" xlink:href="#_6p-circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="indefinite" values="600; 0" 
 restart="always"
  dur="2s" repeatCount="1"  
  fill="remove"  
  calcMode="linear" 
  stroke-opacity="1"
 />
</defs>
<g id="1p">
 <circle id="_1p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" cx="103.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="2p">
 <circle id="_2p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="158.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="3p">
 <circle id="_3p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="210.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="4p">
 <circle id="_4p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="262.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="5p">
 <circle id="_5p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="314.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
<g id="6p">
 <circle id="_6p-circle" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#000" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="366.5" cy="194.5" r="20"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: it worked, thank you! The final svg was way more complicated, had a little troubles with adaptation of click listener on group of sequential animations, but finally it's working fine.